# How to edit pdf metadata from command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, metadata

I need a command line tool for editing metadata of pdf-files.

I'm using a Aiptek MyNote Premium tablet for writing my notes and minutes on this device, import them later and convert them to pdf automatically with a simple script using inkscape and ghostscript.

Is there any command line tool to add some categories to the pdf's metadata, so i can find the pdf later (e.g. with gnome-do) by categories?

Update: I tried the solution with pdftk and it works, but it seems that gnome-do doesn't take care of pdf-metadata. Is there a way to get gnome-do to do that?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Give `exiftool` a try; it is available from the package `libimage-exiftool-perl` in the repositories.

As an example, If you have a pdf file called `drawing.pdf` and you want to update its metadata, use the utility, `exiftool`, in this way:

```
exiftool -Title="This is the Title" -Author="Happy Man" -Subject="PDF Metadata" drawing.pdf
```

For some reason the Subject entered ends up in the keywords field of the metadata in the pdf file. not a problem in some cases, even desirable, however, this may be problematic: evince and the nautilus metadata previewer do not show this, but Adobe Acrobat viewer and PDF-XChange viewer do.

The program will create a backup of the original file if you do not use the `-overwrite_original` switch. This means a duplicate will exist in the folder where the updated pdf is. From the example above, a file named `drawing.pdf_original` will be created.

Use the overwrite switch at your own risk. My suggestion is not to use it and script something to move this file to a better location just in case.

Comment: This works fine, thank you. It's curious how much tools come along with ubuntu / linux. I wish to know more about all this stuff :-). Meanwhile i used pdfmod after importing my files. This is a nice little application.

Comment: Note that: *"[All metadata edits are reversible](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PDF.html). While this would normally be considered an advantage, it is a **potential security problem** because old information is **never actually deleted** from the file."*

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty if you want to purge all remnant and unused metadata entries, you can linearize the PDF file right after processing it with exiftool. This is described in more detail in [this Github gist](https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384).

Comment: @Glutanimate Nice link, but not 100 % convincing/authorative IMHO. Eg, why does it cite `exiftool` without mentionin the above limitation? Because it's just a "gist" and doesn't claim to be bullet-proof / hold water? Could be that linearization does indeed go in the direction of anon., but does it go *all the way*?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Well, of course it's not an authoritative source but that's only because nobody ever took the time to write one. However, I can assure that the method described by the author works. Try it out yourself: 1.) Take a PDF that has some tags and "delete" all metadata with `exiftool -overwrite_original -all:all="" file.pdf`; 2.) Use `exiftool -PDF-update:all= file.pdf` to confirm that there is still old metadata present; 3.) linearize the file with  `qpdf --linearize file.pdf`; 4.) Check again, like you did in 2.); all metadata should be gone;

Comment: 5.) confirm that the file has been purged of all metadata by looking at the PDF dictionary (`pdfinfo -meta file.pdf`)

Comment: Thank you. It also worked like a charm on my Mac with macOS 10.12 and  "homebrew".

Comment: Works perfectly.  I regularly want to copy the metadata from one PDF to another, in which case `exiftool -overwrite_original -tagsFromFile <srcfile> <destfile>` is what I need (the option `-overwrite_original` overwrites the original `<destfile>`).

Comment: Do note that pretty important bit from the `exiftool` manual : *"3) Changes to PDF files by ExifTool are reversible (by deleting the update with "-PDF-update:all=") because the original information is never actually deleted from the file.  So ExifTool alone may not be used to securely edit metadata in PDF files."*

Comment: A shell specific observation, but when installed from apt, the Bash _file name completion_ does not work if options are written on the command line, e.g. `exiftool -Title="Smthg" filenam[tab]`. Filename completion only works with: `exiftool finenam[tab]`. There is no completion script for exiftool in `/usr/share/bash-completion/`, so this annoying problem could (should) be fixed there.

Answer (score 23):

You can edit PDF metadata using `pdftk`. Check out the `update_info` (or `update_info_utf8` if you need accented characters) parameter. As for data file, below is an example:

```
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Mt-Djing: multitouch DJ table
InfoKey: Subject
InfoValue: Dissertation for Master degree
InfoKey: Keywords
InfoValue: DJing, NUI, multitouch, user-centered design
InfoKey: Author
InfoValue: Pedro Lopes
```

([Source](http://web.ist.utl.pt/%7EPedro.Lopes/blog/?p=1652))

Comment: Ok, this means i have to export the metadata to a textfile, edit them and reimport the textfile. Is there a way to directly set a single metadata from command-line?

Comment: There may be, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: `pdftk` seems to Unicode characters in the metadata.

Comment: I had some problem using `pdftk` on new pdfs (newer versions are encrypted via AESV2). Seems like it's discontinued. `exiftool` was working better.

Comment: @s1lv3r but exiftool isn't allowing for custom tags, isn't it? I have a problem where pdftk "hangs" on dump_data for a PDF, but after using exiftool on it, and adding 'author' thag, it works. I should get a pdf test program

Comment: to use pdftk, what you need to do is: 1) `pdftk book.pdf dump_data output report.txt` 2) edit report.txt 3) `pdftk book.pdf update_info report.txt output bookcopy.pdf`

Comment: You can add step (4) to @craq's above: so as not to mess with the file creation info: `touch -r book.pdf bookcopy.pdf`. This will give the new file the old file's creation/modification dates.  However, I note that after @craq's 3 steps, my resulting file is 20% larger than the original one.

Comment: The link specified for 'Source', is no longer valid; it is 404'd.

Comment: Unfortunately, this functionality is [broken as of pdftk 2.02](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788660).

Comment: @craq your comment should be an answer as it has the clearest instructions. I would upvote it.

Comment: @Pont seems to be working again in `pdftk` version 3.0.9.

Answer (score 12):

### Using Ghostview

Install `ghostscript` with:

```
$ sudo apt install ghostscript
```

Create a file named `pdfmarks` with similar content:

```
[ /Title (Document title)
  /Author (Author name)
  /Subject (Subject description)
  /Keywords (comma, separated, keywords)
  /ModDate (D:20061204092842)
  /CreationDate (D:20061204092842)
  /Creator (application name or creator note)
  /Producer (PDF producer name or note)
  /DOCINFO pdfmark
```

then combine this `pdfmarks` file with a PDF, PS or EPS input file:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf original.pdf pdfmarks
```

Source: http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on the `pdftk` method, which is nice because it shows you everything that's being set, at the same time as allowing you to change anything you like, here is a script (for your `.bashrc` or other aliases file) to do it with one command. This creates a new version of the file you want to edit, opens your favourite editor with the metadatafile, and then implements your changes and sets the file creation/modification time on the modified PDF file to be the same as the original. To use it, after resourcing your `.bashrc` file, just type

`editPDFmetadata myfile.pdf`

Here's the alias:

```
editPDFmetadata() {
OUTPUT="${1}-new.pdf"
METADATA="tmp${1}-report.txt"
pdftk "${1}" dump_data output "$METADATA"
$EDITOR "$METADATA"
pdftk "${1}" update_info "$METADATA"  output "$OUTPUT"
touch -r "${1}" "${OUTPUT}"
}
```

Simply place the definition above into the `.bashrc` file in your home folder, then open a new terminal and it will be ready to use.

Comment: This is excellent, but I recommend quoting your variables when using them (e.g.: `pdftk "${1}" dump_data ...`) in case of PDF files with spaces or other special characters in their filename.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Thanks! Done. Hopefully the filename does not have quotes in it?

Comment: Thanks! About quotes: Not in my case, at least :)
(Sorry - I just noticed there is one `$METADATA` that is still unquoted, on the second `pdftk` line. I don't know if AU will allow such a small edit though.)

Answer (score 7):

I needed to blank out the *Author* field in a PDF exported from LibreOffice. None of the solutions listed above worked for me, so I used `hexedit` and overwrote the *Author* field. Blunt instrument but effective!

In detail:

1. Run:

   ```
   $ hexedit file.pdf
   ```
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to ASCII.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to search for "Author".
4. Skip the `<FEFF` at the start of the field.
5. Write `0` over all characters (except I preserved three `0x03` characters... YMMV) up to the closing `>`.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.

Comment: Smartest solution of them all, other solutions only work for simple mods

Answer (score 6):

I have extensively tested the functionality of pdftk and exiftool. I have used exiftool both at command line and through a graphical window. These have been tested for small, medium size and very large PDF documents and found to have issues with the largest and most complex PDF documents. In my experience, the pdftk / exiftool have top functionality only for small and for simple-in-formatting PDF documents. For large and complex PDF documents (eg more than 80 pages with multiple fonts) images and/or characters may fall out from the last pages after the metadata has been edited. The solution may be in the use of Ghostview, which I saw just now. No doubt these programs will improve with time.

In the meantime, I have found a solution in using the present form of Wine in Ubuntu with a one-window tiny freeware program, which works also for these large, complex PDF documents: BeCyPDFMetaEdit (available eg from freeware libraries like SoftPedia).

Comment: It looks like BeCyPDFMetaEdit has been discontinued, as of Nov. 2018. The last available website I see for it is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180929111456/http://www.becyhome.de/becypdfmetaedit/description_eng.htm

Answer (score 4):

Another command is ebook-meta (avaiable after installing Calibre).

To see tags:

```
ebook-meta file.pdf
```

To change title:

```
ebook-meta file.pdf -t "Conversations with Ambrosius"
```

Comment: Neat! I like that it handles --date="1986 Feb 1" and converts it into the format PDFs use internally, whereas exiftool required me to use --CreateDate="1986:02:01 12:00:00Z". Unfortunately, ebook-meta's --date option changes neither the creation date nor the modification date in the PDF. Also, it has nothing like exiftool's "-preserve" option to preserve the file's modification timestamp.

Comment: How would one go setting `Producer` and `Creator` to separate values?

Answer (score 1):

This is in the [act](https://github.com/lancejpollard/act) library so you can edit PDF metadata from the command-line here as well.

```
$ npm install @lancejpollard/act -g
$ act update input.pdf --title foo --author bar --subject baz -k one -k two
```

You can also set `-p` publisher, `-c` creator, `-t0` created date, and `-tn` updated date.