# How to rename a file title?

Tags: nautilus, pdf

How do I change a file title?

Nautilus properties dialogue only allows me to rename the file name, not the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit pdf metadata from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27381/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-from-command-line) && https://askubuntu.com/q/401114/480481