# add description to pdf

Tags: pdf

Is there a software that adds descriptions to pdf documents (eg summary of a paper), either immediately visible at GUI, right-click properties or at the command line. Any will do. Preferably full descriptions over tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit pdf metadata from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27381/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-from-command-line)

Comment: I was hoping more for a GUI related answer but I guess that will do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Libre Office Draw comes installed by default on Ubuntu. It will let you add text to pdf's that don't have form fields as well as add graphics and sometimes move existing ones depending on how the pdf was saved.

Comment: It seems to me that Draw can edit a pdf ,as in,  its' contents. I'm talking about a description that is available without opening it, simply by scrolling through the directory